# PostgreSQL .pgpass file with multiple passwords?

Tags: linux, postgresql, cloudera, pg-dump

Hello I am useing postgresql pg_dump to dump a databases but there are multiple databases on the postgresql instance can the .pgpass file have multiple databases passwords in it.

pg_dump command: -h = host -p =port -U = user -w = look for .pgpass file

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 7432 -U scm -w > /nn5/scm_server_db_backup
```

.pgpass file looks like this:

```
   localhost:7432:scm:scm:password
```

There are other databases running on this instance of postgresql and I would like to add them to the file so i only need to use one .pgpass file 
I think the users in the dump command needs to change also?

```
   localhost:7432:amon:amon:password
```

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So adding multiple lines to the .pgpass file i was able to do more than 1 databases at a time.

EX: .pgpass file:

```
localhost:7432:scm:scm:password
localhost:7432:amon:amon:password
```

and the dump commands needs to be in script file one after the other.

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 7432 -U scm -w > /nn5/scm_server_db_backup
pg_dump -h localhost -p 7432 -U amon -w > /nn5/scm_server_db_backup
```